# Refresh UpdatePanel using javascript without page reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to display data from XML in UpdatePanel(inside DIV1). DIV1 is hidden, but is displayed onclick of DIV2. I want the data to be loaded in DIV1 when DIV2 is clicked and not on page load. So far, I have come upto the below solution.
**---Default.aspx-----**

```
<div id="tool2" onclick="__doPostBack('ReloadThePanel','');">This is DIV2</div>

<div class="contentpanel2">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" GroupingText="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatebloglist" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ReloadThePanel" EventName="Click" />
             </Triggers>
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Literal ID="litResults" runat="server" />
             </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
      <asp:Button ID="ReloadThePanel" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
     </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

**----Default.aspx.cs----**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "ReloadThePanel")
        {
            ReloadThePanel_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }

    }

    public void ReloadThePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readXML();
    }
```

But, the problem with this solution is that data is loaded in DIV1 when DIV2 is clicked, but the page is reloaded in the process. I don't want the page load onclick of the div. Please suggest.

Comment: I've tested your code "as is" in emty asp.net project, and there is no page refresh.

Comment: @Uriil, I think the page is always refreshed on __doPostBack call. I am still facing the issue. Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: Set the ChildrenAsTriggers property to true on UpdatePanel.

Comment: @aria, I found that ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true by default on UpdatePanel. Still, by setting the property explicitly didn't solve this. Thanks btw.

Comment: @sahaj Yes I knew but I want to set it to true explicitly, Check your HTML tags closed all.